# Oracle SQL - Pivot on Date

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, crosstab

I have the following data:

```
**TYP                                       CNT     VALUE     ORDER_DATE**
Collect from Store - Payment Confirmed      1397    3000      28-OCT-2021
Collect from Store - Payment Confirmed       277    1500      27-OCT-2021
```

I want to show result as:

```
**TYP                                      VALUE     27-OCT-2021  28-OCT-2021**
Collect from Store - Payment Confirmed      4500         277        1397
```

How to apply the pivot?

Comment: Are there only 2 rows or they can be dynamic upto 100s of rows?

Comment: dynamic.. can be multiple

Comment: Then you would need a dynamic pivot, which is more work, but there are lots of examples. However, this seems like something an application or reporting layer should handle, perhaps.

Comment: You can check out [`these questions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-pivot%2boracle?tab=Frequent) for dynamic cases